# how to hide scrollbar in ie8 in this specific case?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, scrollbar

I am trying to make IE to hide a scrollbar, The recommended recipes do not seem to work:

E.g. this.scrollbar='no'; <- no effect
this.style.overflow='hidden'; <- this hides the vertical scrollbar and introduces a horizonal one.
this.style.overflow-y='hidden'; <-- this freezes IE8.

What else could i do?

Found out....  this.style.overflowY='hidden'; works.

Comment: There's a typo (pverflow-y) in your question. Have you made sure it's not also in the code you're testing?

Comment: If "overflow=hidden" introduces a horizontal scroll, then something else is likely wrong. It should hide both (which is the justification for an explicit overflow-x/overflow-y). Make sure you are in IE8 (or "Emulate IE7" at the very worst case) mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
document.body.scroll = "no";
```

This is strictly IE only.